# TMX tiles not rendered when base outside camera range (Andengine)

Tags: android, andengine, tmx

I am using isometric TMX layers in Andengine to render a TMX map I created with "Tiled". The isometric TMX map uses 64x32px fields. Some tiles like walls are sized 64x128px. How can I force these walls to be rendered, even when their 64x32px base is outside the camera range?

[image: tmx sample]